# Return multiple nested dictionaries from Tcl

Tags: dictionary, nested, tcl

I have a Tcl proc that creates two dictionaries from a large file. It is something like this:

```
...
...
proc makeCircuitData {spiceNetlist} {
 #read the spiceNetlist file line by line
 # create a dict with multilevel nesting called elementMap that will have the following structure:
 # elementMap key1 key2 value12
 # elementMap keyA keyB valueAB
 # and so on
 # ... some other code here ...
 # create another dict with multilevel nesting called cktElementAttr that will have the following structure:
 # cktElementAttr resistor leftVoltageNode1 rightVoltageNode1 resValue11
 # cktElementAttr resistor leftVoltageNode2 rightVoltageNode2 resValue12
 # cktElementAttr inductor leftVoltageNode2 rightVoltageNode2 indValue11
 # cktElementAttr inductor leftVoltageNode2 rightVoltageNode2 indValue12
 # cktElementAttr capacitor leftVoltageNode2 rightVoltageNode2 capValue11
 # ... so on...   
}
```

I want to return these two nested dictionaries: 
    cktElementAttr and elementMap from the above types of procedures as these two dictionaries get used by other parts of my program.

What is the recommended way to return two dictionaries from Tcl procs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
return [list $cktElementAttr $elementMap]
```

Then, at the caller, you can assign the return value to a list:

```
set theDictionaries [makeCircuitData ...]
```

or assign them to different variables:

```
lassign [makeCircuitData ...] cEltAttr elmMap
```

In Tcl 8.4 or older (which are obsolete!), you can (ab)use `foreach` to do the job of `lassign`:

```
foreach {cEltAttr elmMap} [makeCircuitData ...] break
```

Documentation:
[break](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/break.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: Both work. I thougt I was smart, re-invented the wheel and came up with the tcl 8.4 solution. In 2022. Good answer and I am getting too old.